# Password Protection Issue in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

In my Solution Web API is in a different project. WebAPI sends User records along with their Password also. In order to not send the password I added `[JsonIgnore] Attribute` for Password Property. Like below

```
[JsonIgnore]
public String Password { get; set; }
```

This is now, not sending the password info in any user record. Now the problem is, When I Serialize the class data to send UserName and Password to WebAPI for User Authentication....this does not send Password to Web API.

Kindly suggest the corrective action

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks for the very useful comment. +1. Password is already in encrypted state. Still I don't want to expose it.